# ArrayLib is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, helper

I am a very very beginner with script writing. Basically I've had a couple scripts written for me that I've been able to manage throughout the years. however a script that I've had running for years suddely stopped working. Nothing that I'm aware of has changed. ( honestly I don't know what im looking at to even recognize if something has) Please Please if there's anyone that can help it would be greatly appreciated. ReferenceError: ArrayLib is not defined (line 50, file "Code")
Please please please

```
function OOU() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1L9f8wx3OYnry_UocEpBapuEmismMd6XYBO1Kl9e4duE");         
var unitsoou = ss.getSheetByName("ROSS_OOU_Import")  
var numRows = unitsoou.getDataRange();                       
var names = unitsoou.getRange(2, 4, 200).getDisplayValues();       

var sheetName = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("1");
var unitSched = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);               
PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("1", "UNIT_427")


var currentDate =  Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "MM/dd/yyyy");     
var changeDate = unitSched.getRange(4,38).getValue();                           
var newChangeDate = new Date(changeDate.getTime() + 3600000*24)                
var newChangeDate = Utilities.formatDate(newChangeDate, "GMT+1", "MM/dd/yyyy");
if (newChangeDate == currentDate) {                                              
var wp = unitSched.getRange(1,1).getValue();                                    
wp = wp + 1                                                                   
var newSheetName = "UNIT_" + wp                                               
PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("1",newSheetName)         
unitSched = ss.getSheetByName(newSheetName)                                  
}
unitSched.getRange(7,2,530,3).clearContent()                 
for (i =7; i <= 530; ++i) {                                  
var name2 = unitSched.getRange(i, 40).getValue()           

if (name2 != "#N/A" & name2 != "") {                       

var findName = ArrayLib.indexOf(names, 0, name2);      
    
  
    
if (findName >= 0){                                     
        
var incident = unitsoou.getRange(findName + 2 , 1).getDisplayValue()      
var reqNumber = unitsoou.getRange(findName + 2, 3).getDisplayValue()      
unitSched.getRange(i, 2).setValue("OOU")                           
unitSched.getRange(i, 3).setValue(incident)                         
unitSched.getRange(i, 4).setValue(reqNumber)                        
        
}
}
}  
}

function onOpen() {
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
// Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
ui.createMenu('Run ROSS OOU')
.addItem('ROSS OOU', 'OOU')
.addToUi();
}
```

Comment: Did you add the library to your project? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries#new-editor_1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation / Issue:

Initially, I thought you made a typo but I just realized that you are using this external library: [2D Arrays Library](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/2d-arrays-library).

Most likely you haven't installed the library for that script. Well, in that case you can follow the instructions in the link I provided and actually do it.

However, reading the documentation of this library, I found how `ArrayLib.indexOf(names, 0, name2)` works:

[image: example]

Essentially you pass `names` which is your 2D array (but in this case a column array), then you pass the index which is the column number to look for (in your case `0` column) and then `name2` is the value to search for. Well, you don't need a library to do that. You can directly use the built in `indexOf` method by yourself.

### Solution:

**Replace:**

```
var findName = ArrayLib.indexOf(names, 0, name2);
```

**With:**

```
var findName = names.flat().indexOf(name2);
```

Essentially, we [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)ten the array to make it `1D` so we can then work with [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) directly and get the first index at which `name2` appears in `names` or get `-1` if it is not present.

- This will do exactly what the helper/library code would do and you don't depend anymore on this external library.
- Assuming that the rest of your code works and as far as I can see, you are not using a method of this `ArrayLib` library anywhere else, your code should be working fine after this modification.

Keep in mind that your code needs a lot of improvements as it is iteratively using API methods and it does not respect the [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices). However, the optimization of the code is not related to your question nor to this website (unless that is part of the solution itself). I would advice you to learn a little Google Apps Script so you can optimize your code, but also maintain/modify  it when needed.

Comment: Like I stated before I am new comer to all this.......... I'm extremely impressed with the quickness of your response and the detailed explanation and resolution!! I am a California Fightfighter and in charge of a scheduling program that schedules roughly 350 employees. until now i have been able to utilize interns from a local college. That resource has all but dried up and I thank you again for your help!! I wish I could clean up my skills but honestly I dont have any. I would LOVE to make this more efficient but Im not there YET lol. THANKS AGAIN!!!